# How to append a word into a txt file, at the correct position (alphabetic order) in Java

Tags: java, treeset

There is a text file: dictionary.txt, each line has a single English word, the words are ordered alphabetically from A to Z.

Now I want to insert a word each time, into that dictionary.txt file, at its correct position.

Except using `Set<String> dictionary = new TreeSet<String>();`, which means I have to add each word already in that .txt file into an Array or a Set, sort it, then put the contents back to .txt file.

Is there any other simpler solution or method? Such that I can add the words into its correct position directly into the .txt file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the language you're using, inserting something into a file (not at the end) requires rewriting the file from that point to the end (everything after that point, that was already in the file, will be at a slightly different place in the file (and therefore a different physical place on the disc)).

You can seek to the position in the file at which you want to insert, then write the new word, followed by everything (already in the file) after it.

If you want a file holding a sorted list, with the ability to efficiently add to it, this is usually done using an index (either in a separate file, or part of the same file). The file would not be physically sorted, and you would instead update the index when adding a word. You could use a database system (such as SQLite) to do this for you.